# LAN and WLAN networks under same IP range

Tags: routing, ipv4, subnet

I'm a newbie in network stuff and haven't enough knowledge to do what I'm wanting for now, so I need your help, please.

I've  two networks, a wired and another wireless.

The wired one is between two computers that acts as routers/gateways. The first one receives provider's Internet link and routes to second, which manages a wireless network and routes Internet to it's clients.

```
                         |            |    wired     |            |    wireless    | Client
[Internet link] ======== | Computer 1 | ============ | Computer 2 | ============== | Client
                         |            |              |            |                | etc.
```

Currently, wired network has a /30 IP range and wireless a /24. They are distinct ranges (i.e. 192.168.45.0/30 for wired and 172.16.45.0/24 for wireless). This setting doesn't allow Clients reach Computer 1 or vice versa.

What I want is to have everything within the same IP range, making possible Computer 1 reach Computer 2 and Clients, Clients reach Computer 2 and Computer 1 and Computer 2 reach Computer 1 and Clients. Ultimately, everyone be able to communicate with everyone.

How can I make this? I've searched a lot but found nothing useful, maybe I'm not searching for right term.

Comment: That requires bridging, and how to configure it depends on your OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For outbound traffic (going from right to left in your diagram) you just need to make sure each machine has a default gateway set which matches the next hop IP e.g. the clients will have `computer2` as their default gateway, `computer2` will have `computer1` as its default gateway and so on. For traffic going in the other direction (from left to right) all you need is for `computer1` to have a static route that tells it which next hop to use to send traffic destined for `172.16.45.0/24`; in your case that is `computer2`. So the route command on `computer1` would be something like

```
$ route add -net 172.16.45.0/24 gw 192.168.45.x
```

`computer2` doesn't need a static route for `172.16.45.0/24` as it is directly connected to that network

---

EDIT

> What I want is to have everything within the same IP range,

You could use the free remaining addresses in the 192.168.45.x range, however you need to choose a subnet that does not overlap the existing subnet `192.168.45.0/30`. The best choice would be `192.168.45.128/25` as that gives you the most usable addresses (125):

```
network:    192.168.45.128
broadcast:  192.168.45.255
subnet:     255.255.255.128
usable IPs: 192.168.45.129 - 192.168.45.254
```

Comment: Thanks, this appear to solve the routing problem. But what about to have both networks under same IP range? Ex.: [Network 1 -> Network: 192.168.45.0; Netmask: 255.255.255.252; Available IPs: 192.168.45.1-2; Broadcast: 192.168.45.3] [Network 2 -> Network: 192.168.45.4; Netmask: 255.255.255.128; Available IPs: 192.168.45.5-131; Broadcast: 192.168.45.132] Can I do this? If yes, will this setting allow everyone-to-everyone communication as I'm wanting? Thanks, bye.

Comment: `[Network 2 -> Network: 192.168.45.4; Netmask: 255.255.255.128; Available IPs: 192.168.45.5-131; Broadcast: 192.168.45.132]` That is not a valid network for 2 reasons: a) it overlaps with the existing subnet and would cause a conflict b) the broadcast address 192.168.45.132 is not possible with netmask 255.255.255.128